# DigitalOcean managed MySQL 8 database has massive amount of "threads created"

Tags: digital-ocean

I've read and re-read DO's description of [threads created](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/mysql/how-to/monitor-databases/#master-server-metrics) and can't for the life of me figure out what's going on. Is this really implying that 650000 threads are being created every second? That can't be right.

Someone help me decipher what this graph implies please.

[image]

Comment: Check if the value of "Threads created" is not cumulative.

Comment: I had to reach out to their support, but yes, it is cumulative - that helps explain the number.

Comment: Divide threads_created by uptime to determine Threads_created per second since instance start for a meaningful number.  Creating threads is expensive in resource consumption.  A usually safe calculation after 24 hours of prime uptime minimum is  max_used_connections * 1.1 for thread_cache_size to minimize the heavy workload of thread creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Threads created"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_created) is a standard status value MySQL servers provide.

> The number of threads created to handle connections. If `Threads_created` is big, you may want to increase the `thread_cache_size` value. The cache miss rate can be calculated as `Threads_created/Connections`.

As far as I know is not per second but rather an incremental ***"counter"*** that (re-)starts at zero whenever MySQL is started and then only increases (like the odometer in a car) and not a ***"gauge"*** that goes up and down whenever load changes (like the speedometer in car).

A really large number of "threads created"  and a steeper incline  would suggest a more heavily loaded database with numerous new and/or concurrent connections and many active queries. The server can't re-use existing threads and must actively create new ones. That has a performance penalty.

When the number of "threads created"  increases more slowly, a large value could maybe also suggest that it has been a long time since the MySQL server was last restarted.

Comment: Thank you, that is much more helpful than the DO description of that value.